Ingress GKE keeps throwing 404
I am really looking for hours and hours. Running in GKE with Ingress GCE.
I keep getting a 404 with only on my .Net WebApi container
I have a .net core webapi running inside a container on port 8080 with a service that accepts through prt 8082.
When I deploy the hello world example https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/samples/container-helloapp-ingress everything works fine
My .net deployment and ingress look like this.
If I do a kubectl port forward I can also not reaching my pod
kubectl port-forward svc/webapi-svc 8080:8080
I get a 404.
What am I missing in my configuration?
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  annotations:
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce"
      kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "true"
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            path: /access
            backend:
              service:
                name: webapi-svc #this is the .Net Core Web API service: NOT WORKING
                port:
                  number: 8082
          - pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            path: /node
            backend:
              service:
                name:  hello-world-deployment-2-service #this is the Node.js service: WORKING
                port:
                  number: 8081

Here is my service and deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: webapi-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: webapi
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: webapi
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: webapi
        image: gcr.io/testblazorapp-417308/webapifork8testing:3
        env:
          - name: ASPNETCORE_URLS
            value: http://+:8080
          - name: ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT
            value: Production
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        livenessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 5
          httpGet:
            path: /
            port: 8080
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 60
          periodSeconds: 30
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 5
        readinessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 10
          httpGet:
            path: /
            port: 8080
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 15
          periodSeconds: 2
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 2
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: webapi-svc
  labels:
    app: webapi
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: webapi
  ports:
  - port: 8082
    targetPort: 8080


It turned out to be something really weird. I deleted my cluster and totally started from scratch. It now works perfect
